# How to filter comments in Wordpress by a meta_value stored in wp_commentdata?

Tags: wordpress

I was able to input in the database of Wordpress, in table wp_commentmeta, through a custom field in the comment form, these datas:

```
meta_id | comment_id | meta_key       | meta_value
--------------------------------------------------
9       | 6          | commentoptions | option1
10      | 7          | commentoptions | option2
```

Now I'm trying to find a way to filter the comments for displaying them in 2 columns on a single page, one column left and one column right, based on the meta_value value. I mean: the first comment has to go in column on te left, and the next comment has to go to the column on the right.

At first, I thought "I'm lucky, just only need to create two div, positioning them with CSS, and filter the comments with wp_list_comments function" but... wp_list_comments function is not able to do that.

Could someone suggest me how can I proceed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It's a  bit late... and I just realized my original answer is specific to post meta data. I will leave my original answer below since it might be useful for grabbing meta fields for a post. At the top you will find the method to get **comment** meta fields.

Assuming these meta values are making their way into the database via wordpress API, the below code will help you pull meta values for a specific comment <s>post</s>.

Revised Answer:

```
<?php 
$comment_id = 123;
$key = "commentoptions"; // change to whatever key you are using
$single = true; // whether or not you want just one or multiple values returned associated with the same key, see comments below about use

$meta_values = get_comment_meta($comment_id, $key, $single); 
?>
```

---

**Original Answer** (applies for getting **post** meta fields)

```
<?php 
$post_id = 123;
$key = "commentoptions"; // change to whatever key you are using
$single = true; // whether or not you want just one or multiple values returned associated with the same key, see comments below about use

$meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single); 
?>
```

You can alternatively use get_post_custom_values() as shown below, which is a nicer way to do it if you have multiple values expected for each key. The above code will do the same if you are using $single = false, but it is not preferred because of how the get_post_meta() function works - if only one value is returned, it gives you the actual string value, otherwise it returns an array of values. The below method will return an array if you have one or multiple values for a key, so it leads to cleaner, more intuitive code.

```
<?php
$post_id = 123;
$key = "commentoptions";

$meta_values = get_post_custom_values($key, $post_id);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, specially because it was so late! I can retrieve the data (meta_value) from the database but... I don't know how to list comments in two columns, based on this meta_value. At first I thought a thing like this: "wp_list_comments( array( 'meta_key' => 'commentoptions', 'meta_value' => 'option1' ) );" but the wp_list_comments doesn't provide this. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: @Morris One way would be to use get_comments() function in WP. This will give you the data for the comments you want (you can specify a post or comment ID to retrieve). The result is an array with all the comment's data.